# How to execute processes parallel for multi web user async socketio application

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-socketio

I am using a python socketio async server. I have several socketio.on processes that can occur in my backend. Each user in my website can send a socket to the backend and execute their own process however, in my terminal, each users process is executing one at a time.

For example:

```
socketio=sio.AsyncServer(cors_allowed_origins="*")

app = web.Application()

socketio.attach(app)

def trainmodel(x, y, username,code):

    ******Over here training the users AI model which takes about 10 seconds to do

    args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir="output",
        num_train_epochs=10,
        per_device_train_batch_size=10,
        optim = "adamw_torch"
    )

    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=args,   
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        #eval_dataset=val_dataset,
        compute_metrics=compute_metrics
     )

    trainer.train()


@socketio.on("sendbackends") 
async def trainit(sid,data,code): 
    trainmodel(x,y,username,code)

@socketio.on("bottoken")
async def handle():
    await socketio.emit("redirect",namespace = "/")


if __name__ =='__main__': 
    web.run_app(app, port=5000)
```

my socket.on functions are running one at a time, however I want every process to run in parallel where it doesnt block the next processes.

Comment: You do not have a lot of details here, but you can't really run CPU intensive tasks in an asynchronous application. The CPU work needs to happen in a different process ideally, or at least in a different thread.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg hello I have just updated the post

Comment: I have nothing to change to what I said above. You cannot run CPU intensive tasks in an async application.